# Confused by .Net Core versions

Tags: .net-core

I am quite confused with .net core version numbers. As of May 16, 2018 this [Microsoft support policy page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/Support/Policy) and [GitHub .net core roadmap page](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) show that .Net core version 2.1 is still a release candidate but when I go to the  [SDK download page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows#/sdk) I can download SDK version 2.1.200. This SDK version was available for some time and it does not look like a pre-release version.

This is very confusing. What framework version does SDK include? What is the relationship between these versions?

Comment: I don't see what the fuss is about. You installed version 2.1 of the SDK which installed 2.1.200 of the SDK and 2.0.7 of the runtime. Crystal clear is it not?

Comment: Version numbers are out of sync.  Does it mean that any 2.x SDK can use any 2.x runtime?

Comment: (my comment was a jest, I seriously do not know what I just installed regarding versions)

Comment: I heard many good things about performance and fixes in 2.1 runtime. SDK version 2.1.2 with 2.0 runtime just makes me sad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets pretty confusing but there are multiple packages being "versioned" here, the SDK and the Runtime library. I generally find the easiest way to sort this out is by [Release Notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.1.200-sdk.md):

> The .NET Core SDK 2.1.200 includes .NET Core 2.0.7 Runtime so downloading the runtime packages separately is not needed when installing the SDK.

If you look at the previous SDK version's (`2.1.105`) [release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0.7.md), you'll notice that the SDK has been updated but _not .NET Core (`2.0.7`):

> The .NET Core SDK 2.1.105 includes .NET Core 2.0.7 Runtime so downloading the runtime packages separately is not needed when installing the